# Como resguardar la información de usuario en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, web, seguridad, encriptación

Buenas tardes compañeros, tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una pequeña página web, en la cual los usuarios se van a loggear con un usuario y contraseña y almacenar en una BD usuario y contraseña (encriptada), esa parte ya está superada, mi duda, es en el lado del servidor, cómo protegen ustedes los datos? supongamos que tengo dos tablas, una tabla a) con usuarios y contraseñas y la otra tabla b) con información que no debe ser vista sin haber pasado por la tabla a), he visto que comentan aquí en internet que sería un gran riesgo si alguien pudiera acceder a la tabla de usuarios y obtener los datos de usuario y contraseñas, pero haciendo eso, no obtienen tambien datos de las demas tablas, si yo me sé el server, la contraseña y la base de datos de la tabla de usuario, puedo obtener todas las tablas de esa base y no necesitaria los usuarios y contraseñas, o no es así? 
Mi pregunta en especifico es como organizan sus tablas? tienen una base de datos solo para usuario y otra para la información? o cual es el mecanismo que utilizan para proteger la información y hacer que mientras el login no sea correcto solo la tabla de usuarios esté disponible?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente la información de registro usuario y  su información están en la misma base de datos y a menudo en la misma tabla o en tablas relacionadas de alguna manera.

Si tienes información sensible almacenada en la base  de datos de los usuarios también debería ser encriptada , no solo la contraseña. Si un atacante se hiciera con el  acceso a la base de datos por un fallo de seguridad , la información sensible estaría protegida de esa forma.

La organización de los datos en la BD no tiene nada que ver con la seguridad , me refiero , es la aplicación quien tiene que controlar el acceso a los datos de la BD y la organización de los datos en la base de datos debería hacerse por criterios de lógica o de rendimiento.

**Sobre la manera de hacerlo.**

No especificas que tecnología usas del lado del servidor pero suponiendo que sea PHP aqui puedes encontrar un tutorial que explica como hacer un sistema de login básico , **solo para efectos de aprendizaje ya que es vulnerable a algunos ataques**.

[Tutorial login](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) . Está en inglés si alguien conoce algún otro en Español agradecería que lo añadiera.

Answer (score 0):

El canal [Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA) en Youtube tiene una muy buena explicación sobre el *almacenamiento de usuarios y contraseñas en bases de datos*. El [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q) está en inglés pero, afortunadamente, tiene subtítulos en **Español**. 
Hay mucha más información sobre este tema en internet.

Otro muy buen artículo se encuentra en el blog de [Enrique Munguía - Almacenamiento seguro de contraseñas](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2016/05/almacenamiento-seguro-de-contrasenas/). De la misma forma que en el vídeo, explica que lo adecuado es encriptar las contraseñas y además agregarles *"Sal"* que es un término que verás bastante referenciado.

### Función Hash

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]